# How to run nextjs app over https in production mode?

Tags: next.js, https

I can't make it run over https.

I have a domain name well configured on my server.
I have a docker file and a docker-compose, i have "443:443" in the port in the docker-compose.

I created a server.js file in which I have this :

```
const { createServer } = require("https");
const { parse } = require("url");
const next = require("next");
const fs = require("fs");
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const PORT = 443;
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
const httpsOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("./certificate/private.key"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("./certificate/certificate.crt"),
};

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer(httpsOptions, (req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
    handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
  }).listen(PORT, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      throw err;
    }

    console.log(`> Server started on https://localhost:${PORT}`);
  });
});
```

When it deploys I can access via https://ip but with https://domain it doesn't work.
LWS says that there is nothing on the dedicated server. I changed my dns zone 72 hours ago so DNS is well propaged.

I launched at the moment this way : `yarn build; node server.js`

I don't understand why it doesn't work, anything would help me
Thx.

In localhost everything works fine except I reach via https://localhost.

Any idea ?